# get a value froma a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

This is a simple example of a question i have about how tu acces to a value that is in a list of diccionaries.I want to change the value of color only when the 'sprite' is equal to 10, the def of make() is only a function that represents how i would save the dictionaries in the list, is simplified from my bigger program.But the fact is that it gives me an error when i try to equalize the value of 'sprite' to 10, with this little programm i only want to find out how can i equal that without give me any error. Thank you

```
tortugas =[]
def make():
    tortuga = {}
    tortuga['sprite'] = 10
    tortuga['color']= "pink"
    tortuga['angulo'] = 90
    tortugas.append(tortuga)
    perro= {}
    perro['sprite']= 8
    perro['color']= "black"
    perro['angulo']= 5
    tortugas.append(perro)
alex= make()
print(tortugas)
color="red"
for n in tortugas:
    if 10==tortugas[0]['sprite']:
        for m in tortugas[n]:
            tortuga['color']= color
```

This code give me this error: 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in line 16

More simplified it would be something like this:

```
tortugas=[{'sprite': 10, 'color': "pink},{'sprite':8,'color':"blue"}]
color="red"
for n in tortugas:
    if tortugas[n]['sprite']== 10:
        for m in tortugas[n]:
            tortuga['color']= color
```

I want to change the color of the first dictionary only whenin that condition, not for all the dictionaries.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Rather than saying "it gives me an error" it would be much better if you include the full error message and state where it is occurring in your code. Even better, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `alex is None`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback of the error, not just the final line.

Comment: The error is on line 19 of the posted code: `for m in tortugas[n]:`. `n` is a dictionary, and I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an error because when you use :

```
for n in tortugas:
```

the value of n is `{'sprite': 10, 'color': "pink"}`, so, you can't use `tortugas[n]`.

If you want n as the index of your list, use `for n in range(len(tortugas))` insead.

Comment: .. or, possibly more obvious, replace `tortugas[n]` with just `n` as it "is" each element of `tortugas` in turn.